TypeScript compiler suddenly became more strict
I am trying to build a Node.js project from a few years ago and I'm encountering TypeScript compiler issues that were not present back in the days. Although I am using the exact same node version my project fails to build. The GitHub Actions workflows from that time also went through successfully, but also not anymore.
The TS compiler is actually correct with the complaints, but I want to compile it to find the cause of a regression and I don't want to fix hundreds of these new errors.
/Users/user/Desktop/g2d/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
../g2d/src/main.ts(140,40): error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
../g2d/src/main.ts(199,40): error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
../g2d/src/main.ts(240,11): error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
../g2d/src/main.ts(244,42): error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
../g2d/src/main.ts(272,42): error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
../g2d/src/main.ts(307,42): error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.

All dependencies in package.json are locked to its minor version, and I am using the same node version 14.17.6. Can anyone explain me why my project fails with a seamingly more strict setting?
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "some-dependency": "1.2.3",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.2",
    ...
  }

The tsconfig.json looks as follows:
{
  "ts-node": {
    "swc": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Basic configuration
    "incremental": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "ES2021",

    // Type checking options
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": false,

    // Code quality options
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,

    // Module resolution
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    // Library definitions
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES2021"
    ],

    // Skip unnecessary checks
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}


What does your tsconfig.json look like? Have you made any changes to it?

No changes to the tsconfig.json. I have attached the file to the post

While outside the scope of the question as asked (I admit), it's important to note your dependencies are very old - the most notable here being Node v14, which was EOL'd in April 2023. That means Node (and probably many of your dependencies) have not received even critical security-related patches in quite some time. It's not advisable and risky to run this code anywhere near a production system or with data that you care anything about.

Fully agree, this is just for local debugging to find the cause of a regression. The deps of the production code is up to date

Can you also share a [mre] of some of this code & reasonable amount of context which is triggering these errors? Are they try/catch blocks, where error TS2571 is most common?

When the compiler "suddenly" becomes more strict, typically a differnt version is used. How do you compile your package? Just by calling tsc? It might be you have a newer version of typescript installed globally and by just doing tsc in the project directory this newer version might be used. What is the output of tsc --version and which tsc when executed in your project directory?
